# Flask - add user input fields dynamically to call function

Tags: python, html, flask, input, dynamic

I have specific functionality that I want to implement into my program, however I have no idea where to start. I am currently using flask to add two numbers together. I have a html file to take the 2 inputs. An Input num function to take the 2 numbers and pass them to another function which will then be added together and saved to a log file which will then be presented on another HTML page. I know there is an easier way to do this but I am building the functionality of the program this way as it will be used for a much larger and complex program later on. I used this example for simplicity purposes.

main.py

```
import sys
from flask import request, render_template, Flask, session, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hjshjhdjah kjshkjdhjs'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def inputNum():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        num1 = request.form.get('num1')
        session["num1"] = num1
        num2 = request.form.get('num2')
        session["num2"] = num2
        return redirect(url_for("results"))
    return render_template("inputNum.html")

@app.route('/results')
def results():
    if "num1" and "num2" in session:
        num1 = session["num1"]
        num2 = session["num2"]
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        log_file = open("message.log", "w")
        sys.stdout = log_file
        addNum(num1, num2)
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        log_file.close()
        with open("message.log", "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
        return app.response_class(content, mimetype='text/plain')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('inputNum'))

def addNum(num1, num2):
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    sum = num1 + num2
    print(sum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True)
```

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
        <title>Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Log file ...</h1>
        <script>
           // function for adjusting iframe height to log size
            function resizeIframe(obj) {
              obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
            }
          </script>
        <iframe src="{{ url_for('results') }}" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

inputNum.hmtl

```
<form action="{{ url_for("inputNum")}}" method="post">
<label for="num1">um1:</label>
<input type="number" id="num1" name="num1" placeholder="num1">
<label for="num2">num2:</label>
<input type="number" id="num2" name="num2" placeholder="num2">
<button type="submit">ADD</button>
```

What I need is a button on the inputNum.html page that will create another set of input boxes that will use the functionality and display the results in the results page as well.

For example being able to add multiple sets of numbers on the same page.

I have no idea where to start so some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited:

You can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn"> Add new fields </button>
<form action="{{ url_for("inputNum")}}" method="post">
  <div id="ip_div">
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit for addition</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var num = 2; // adds 2 fields at a time

var createInputs = function () {
  $("#ip_div").append('<form id="form"></form>');
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    $("#form").append("<input></input>");
  }
};

$("#btn").click(function () {
  createInputs();
  //create unique ID for each input
  $("#form")
    .find("input")
    .each(function (i) {
      $(this).attr("id", "num" + i);
      $(this).attr("placeholder", "num" + i);
    });
});
```

You can test it here: https://codepen.io/sumant-agnihotri/pen/bGWrOvK

Comment: in case this does not make sense (maybe you are not comfortable with JS), I can add more details to the answer.

Comment: HI Sumant, thank you for the quick reply:)

I have no knowledge of javascript so that would be amazing!  

would the dynamic input fields be able to use the same functionality as the original input fields easily?

Comment: in that case, I would recommend you learn some basic JS, I can give you some code but you will hard time importing and debugging it. JS is the basic bread and butter for any HTML page. With JS you can basically do anything on a web page.

Comment: if you dont mind, could you please provide me with the code and ill learn some JS to import it into my program? thanks again

Comment: Here you go: https://codepen.io/sumant-agnihotri/pen/bGWrOvK

Comment: actually I would say that the code you provided is quite understandable even coming from python background (actually I think anyone could understand this piece (and also I have extremely small knowledge of js)), because those functions are super self-explanatory

Comment: @Calllum if this helped you, please accept the answer to close this question :)

Comment: @SumantAgnihotri Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @SumantAgnihotri do i need to link the JS script to the html file for the functionality to work?

Comment: @Calllum yes! you can link it this way: `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi @SumantAgnihotri, I have the fields being added dynamically but I have no idea how to pass the fields independently into the function once they are added. For instance add 5 + 5 and 10 + 10 seperatly, Could you please assist?